# Trouble configuring log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm using Java 6 on Win XP and log4j 1.2.12.  I'm having trouble getting my logs output to a file (no log4j.log appears).  Below is my log4j.properties config, which appears in my war's WEB-INF/classes directory ...

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A2

log4j.appender.A1 = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n

log4j.appender.A2 = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A2.File = c:\apache-tomcat-6.0.33\logs\log4j.log
log4j.appender.A2.Append = true
log4j.appender.A2.DatePattern = '.'yyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.A2.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A2.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n
```

And here's how I access the logger in my class ...

```
public class XMLNode {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(XMLNode.class);

        ...
        logger.debug("test:" + main.toString());
```

Any other ideas what else I should do or check to get my log4j.properties file to appear?  Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem appears to be with the format of the file name.

```
log4j.appender.A2.File = c:\apache-tomcat-6.0.33\logs\log4j.log
```

You  will need to change the file path to use either forward slashes (`/`) or double back slashes (`\\`)

```
log4j.appender.A2.File = c:/apache-tomcat-6.0.33/logs/log4j.log
```

I ran your example above, and when I changed the file path it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

use direct LOGGER.info(String-Message).. hope so you will get the log file..
i think your log file is present but you are not searching it at right place.. find it in